# playframework 2.5.0 Template fail to compile (fresh one)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I would like to get started with play running play 2.5...
but even installing the template with activator "play-java" has an error.

```
Using unsupported version of Play: 2.5.0
```

I have downloaded the full activator package and the minimal.
Both fail on 2 machines(JDK 73).

NO clue how to catch up on this, perhaps some could help me out. I would appreciate it very much.

Bets regards

Comment: At what point did you get this error? I've tried `activator new` with both options `5) play-java` and `6) play-scala` successfully.

Comment: I have exactly the same error and I ran into the same problems when 2.4 was released. It took a couple of weeks before activator was updated to match the templates it was using. In my experience the Play team don't really have a release process as such i.e. nobody checks that the templates will work with the current activator/sbt setup, documentation matches the current release etc

Comment: Try it without the UI

Comment: Well that works, thx.

Comment: I'm absolutely exasperated by this, too.  Spent ages installing all the dependencies, followed all the Activator instructions on a sample play-scala project to get this error repeated ad infinitum.  The workaround doesn't seem to help - if you cd to your project and open it with activator ui, the same thing happens.  I'm appalled.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'activator ui', causes the activator to cycle.  The error message is "Getting 'Using unsupported version of Play: 2.5.0'".  The issue tracking the problem is https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1102.

Using 'activator' without the ui argument is a work-around.

Change directories to the play-java directory and running ./activator without the ui argument.  This brings up the sbt command line.  Sbt commands help, about, tasks, update, compile, test, and run work. A web browser pointed at localhost:9000 will contain a text field with "You're using Play 2.5.0" as content.

The "run" command starts a Netty server. Application interaction is possible using localhost:9000 in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a project without the UI by using something like

```
activator new my-app play-scala
```

Answer (score 0):

Play framework requires java 8 since 2.4 version
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Java-8-support

Comment: I know > thats what i meant with the "73" jre1.8.0_73